# JAX-RS cannot handle a Authorization header with a JWT

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

*Possibly a duplicate but cannot find it lol*

I'm using Quarkus with [quarkus-resteasy](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy) and I'm trying to implement a simple GET method that will syso the headers, but before that, I needed to create a method that could handle a curl request :

```java
@GET
public Response foo() {
    return Response.status(200).entity("Hello world !").build();
}
```

```bash
curl --location 'localhost:8080/api/...''
> Hello world !
```

Everything was fine until i tried to put an Authorization Header with a bearer :

```bash
curl --location 'localhost:8080/api/...' --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGc....'
>
```

I firstly tough Authorization was a "banned" header for some reason.. but if i try the same request with a different value..

```bash
curl --location 'localhost:8080/api/...' --header 'Authorization: foo'
> Hello World !
```

I'm getting an `Hello World !`..

I've also tried to use `@HeaderParam("Authorization")` but same problem, with a Bearer I cannot "target" my endpoint
Anyone ever face this problem ? 
*May the value is too long.. (1795 chars)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem !!

It's simply because I didnt setup my project properly :
https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oidc-bearer-token-authentication

I can't send request with a bearer like i'm doing, i've to "configure" the project before.. ups !!